# Restart SQL service instance using C# 3.5

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, process, smo

I have a C# application that has a restore database utility. The restore process consumes a lot of RAM at about 400MB and doesn't give it back to the operating system which is a bit problematic for machines with low memory. For now I'm not limiting my server instance's memory consumption, I'm giving it whatever it wants.

I'd like to restart my server instance using C# code, it frees up the memory used by the restore process. I have looked at the `ServiceController` which is not available on .NET 3.5 so I'm looking for other options. Currently I would like to go one of the following paths:

- SMO
- Process

Can you give me the advantages and disadvantages of the two? Also, are there other options to do this?

Comment: " The restore process consumes a lot of RAM at about 400MB and doesn't give it back to the operating system " - let's see some code....

Comment: @MitchWheat is it the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the SQL instance is using 400 Mb more memory after the restore than before? In what way? Do a comparison of the output of dbcc memorystatus before and after to see *how* SQL is using more memory.

Comment: @MitchWheat I think you are right, there's not much memory usage when I restore database from management studio. also it gets back the memory used. aside from restoring the database, it does execute some scripts which i think eats up the memory. but for the question, the easiest way I can think of to solve it is to restart the server

Comment: restarting a sql server should need to be done rarely. Unless there is a memory buffer pool error in the sql server logs, I wouldn't be rebooting the server (nor would I let anyone else!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following VB code
I guess you can convert it to C# automatically by using a code converter

```
Dim managedComputer As New ManagedComputer()
Dim sqlService As Service
sqlService = managedComputer.Services("MSSQLSERVER")

If sqlService.ServiceState = ServiceState.Stopped Then
    sqlService.Start()
End If
```

You need to add following references to your project

Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement

Microsoft.SqlServer.WmiEnum